# How to get the span id which starts with a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

actually i have two span with ids like this `date_eform` and `time_eform`.

Now i have to get these ids.. and check if the `span` id starts with `date_` then i have to perform some logic. and if `span` id starts with `time_` then another action.

```
 <span id='date_eform'></span><span id='time_eform'></span>
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

so

```
$.each('span[id^="date_"]',function(){
   //your code here
});
```

and

```
$.each('span[id^="time_"]',function(){
   //your code here
});
```

Comment: It's best to provide a code sample too. For archival purposes so the answer can be found here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("span[id^='date_']").something...    
$("span[id^='time_']").something-else...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("span[id^={word}]")
```

Where {word} is the word you want the element id to start with.

The following like will help:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
$('[id^="date_"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery syntax for attribute ends with:

```
$('span[id$="_eform"]')
```

jQuery syntax for attribute starts with:

```
$('span[id^="_eform"]')
```

jQuery syntax for attribute contains:

```
$('span[id*="_eform"]')
```

From what I understand, you should need to do something like:

```
$('span[id$="_eform"]')
```

Then, with an `each` method, test if jQuery-object ids are `date` or `time`.

```
var elements = $('span[id$="_eform"]');
elements.each(function() {
    if(this.id.substring(0,5)=='date') {
        // handle dates
    } else if(this.id.substring(0,5)=='time_') {
        // handle times
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of ways to achieve this, most of those questions are listed in the other answers.

However, if you only have 2 elements, why aren't you just accessing them directly with the ID? Maybe you want to do something to them once an action has been carried out on them? In which case all the methods listed here can't be used.

If you simply want to bind the two selectors you can just use

```
$('#date_eform, #time_eform')...
```

What you're asking for doesn't make too much sense in the context of your question. If you add more details, there may be a better way to do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `id` and `class` for this task; it would make it clearer. Example below:

HTML:

```
<span id='date' class='eform'></span>
<span id='time' class='eform'></span>
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$(".eform").each(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
    case "date":
        // do something
        break;

    case "time":
        // do something
        break;

    default:
        // "id" is not a case
    }
});
```

Example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9hcfx/