# how to select all divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have several hidden divs on a page , some of them having the same class.

```
<div class="chapter-1"></div>
<div class="chapter-1"></div>
```

I prefix my class that way. How do I make all of them to display?
I have tried

```
var id = 1; // get this from other source
$('.chapter-' + id).each().show();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the span id which starts with a word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967164/how-to-get-the-span-id-which-starts-with-a-word)

Comment: It is somewhat a duplicate... not sure if it's considered "exact", as the solution is somewhat different.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, the question is different. This question asks how to show everything with the same class and the other question asks how to retrieve an individual element with only a part of the selector-name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you don't need the each(). you can just do

```
$(".classname").show();
```

so in your case (this will show all elements with class chapter-1).

```
var id = 1;
$(".chapter-"+id).show();
```

if you wish to show every div element with a class that starts with 'chapter-' you can use [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/):

```
$('div[class|="chapter"]').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.chapter-1').show();` or `$('.chapter-1, .chapter-2').show();`

Or, if they don't have a unique class, make them all have a unique class. Such as `<div class="chapter-1 showDiv"></div>` then:

> $('.showDiv').show();

Answer (score 0):

```
$.('[class ^= "classname"]')
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Tims answer you can also extend it to only select divs if you use the class name for other html entities.

```
$('div.classname' + id).show();
```